# dojo-amd-factory-scan:false seems not to work

Tags: dojo, xpages, lotus-notes

I try to load an external JavaScript library like jQuery mobile to my IBM Notes Database. When i add this library i run i to the known amd loader problem.

I found an article that says when i add

```
xsp.client.script.dojo.djConfig="dojo-amd-factory-scan": false
```

to the xps.properties, this will fix this problem but for me it does not work.
Is there anythink else is miss?

Here is the article
http://xomino.com/2013/05/14/xpages-nd9-dojo-1-8-does-not-work-with-other-amd-loaders-and-the-work-around/

[UPDATE]
Using the Extension Library is not a solution

Comment: Did you try this: http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1216

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works for me. hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1216

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is part of the latest Extension Library release on OpenNTF. That's the best practice method for including jQuery.

Comment: but the problem is that the library i use is not in the extension library.